# how to do convert the string properties in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

For example, we have one client record, it has properties: name, gender, email, address, etc.
The name, email, address are all String. 
How to convert the properties to the tensor?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to convert the properties into a tensor with dtype `tf.string`? OR Do you want to convert a `tf.string` into a regular ASCII? Or did you mean something else altogether?

Comment: Just want to convert the properties into a tensor, no matter what data type to choose. Thanks for your question.

Comment: If you are using a `tf.placeholder` for storing the properties, you can just declare a `nameTensor = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string)` and when you are running a session, you can perform (for example) `sess.run(...,{nameTensor:str(name)})` right?

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to convert the email or address to tf.string, because tf.string is "Variable length byte arrays. Each element of a Tensor is a byte array.". We cannot use "aaa@gamail.com" directly, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking for. If its this, it works fine
(I could not post code block in comments, thus here):

```
tr = tf.Variable(initial_value="aaa@gamail.com", dtype=tf.string)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(tr))
    p = tf.assign(tr,"somethingelse")
    sess.run(p)
```

(This is not an answer)

Answer (score 0):

I thought this post solved most of my question.

http://blog.topspeedsnail.com/archives/10399